# Is a distribution with mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)$ always a Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, moment-generating-functions, bernoulli-distribution

I have some parameter $\theta$ which has a certain probability distribution in the interval $\theta \in [0,1]$ and I know that the first two raw moments are equal $E[\theta^2] = E[\theta] = p$.

So $Var\theta = E[\theta^2] - E[\theta]^2 = p(1-p)$.

So it looks and walks like a *Bernoulli* distribution. Is it? Why?

---

`Edit`: Thanks for the hints, all I could reason about for now is that if by absurd it wasn't a Bernoulli distribution then it most exist a point $a \in (0,1)$ s.t. $f(a) > 0$ (where $f$ is the pdf). So:
$$
E[\theta] = \int_0^1 x f(x) dx = p =
E[\theta^2] = \int_0^1 x^2 f(x) dx \\
\int_0^1 x f(x) dx= \int_0^1 x^2 f(x) dx \\
\int_0^1 (x - x^2) f(x) dx = 0
$$

Now the first part $(x - x^2)$ is strictly positive for any $x \in (0,1)$  and is zero only for $x=0$ or $x=1$. $f(x)$ is non-negative by definition since it's a pdf. So in order for an integral of a non-negative function to be exactly 0 we need that non-negative function to be $g(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in [0,1]$. So:
$$
(x - x^2) f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in [0,1]
\iff f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in (0,1)
$$

Is this proof valid? Could this be proved more easily? The fact that I'm talking about a distribution for which I don't know if it's discrete or is continuous makes it very difficult to me.

Comment: Please do not just ask. Work a little and share your thoughts. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Comment: hint: what is the maximum variance an distribution on $[0,1]$ can have subject to mean $p$?

Comment: Hint: Bernoulli distribution is a discrete one.

Comment: @AnneBauval , I edited the question with some of my work after your hints, can you tell me if this proof is valid?

Comment: Your main ideas are great! But since you do not know  if $\theta$ has a density function $f$, it is cleaner (and quicker) to say: $\theta-\theta^2\ge0$ and $E(\theta-\theta^2)=0,$ hence, almost surely, $\theta-\theta^2=0$ i.e. $\theta\in\{0,1\}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I made it more complicated than necessary by talking about $f$ because i didn't see how to approach in a way that was agnostic of the model discreteness/continuity, thanks for showing me! If you post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $θ∈[0,1],$ we have
$$θ−θ^2≥0.$$
On the other hand, by hypothesis,
$$E(θ−θ^2)=0.$$
Therefore, almost surely, $θ−θ^2=0$ i.e. $θ∈\{0,1\},$ i.e. $θ$ has a Bernoulli distribution.